# Control Qt QML SwipeView with Signals/Slots

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, swipeview

I'm very new to Qt, and right now struggling to figure out how to change the index of the SwipeView through a different C++ class. I'd like to make some kind of a signal that emits from the C++ class saying "Swipe Right" or something like that, and having the SwipeView respond. I'm also new to signals and slots, so I might be misunderstanding how they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to control a `QML` element from C ++ the best strategy is to create a `QObject` that has `Q_PROPERTY`, slot and signals and export it to `QML` through `setContextProperty()`, and perform the direct binding or use Connections to connect the signals, in this case it is only necessary to emit a signal and connect it in `QML`.

In the following example I show how to change to the right or left using QPushButton:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

class SwipeManager: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
public slots:
    void moveToRight(){
        emit toRight();
    }
    void moveToLeft(){
        emit toLeft();
    }
signals:
    void toRight();
    void toLeft();
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    SwipeManager manager;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("manager", &manager);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    QWidget w;
    QPushButton left("to left");
    QPushButton right("to right");
    QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout(&w);
    lay->addWidget(&left);
    lay->addWidget(&right);
    QObject::connect(&left, &QPushButton::clicked, &manager, &SwipeManager::moveToLeft);
    QObject::connect(&right, &QPushButton::clicked, &manager, &SwipeManager::moveToRight);
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("SwipeView Test")

    SwipeView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: 4
        Repeater {
            model: 10
            Loader {
                active: SwipeView.isCurrentItem || SwipeView.isNextItem || SwipeView.isPreviousItem
                sourceComponent: Item{
                    Text {
                        text: "Page: "+index
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Connections{
        target: manager
        onToRight: if(view.currentIndex + 1 != view.count) view.currentIndex += 1
        onToLeft: if(view.currentIndex != 0) view.currentIndex -= 1
    }

    PageIndicator {
        id: indicator

        count: view.count
        currentIndex: view.currentIndex

        anchors.bottom: view.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }
}
```

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/52581687).